# How to get call back url value without actual server

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

Our third party company provide me link to get authcode for integrated their Api.When we call that link on browser , we get callback url as https://return.mytest.com/?code=my1234&scope= although getting error message as "This site can’t be reached" .Actaully https://return.mytest.com is no have our side. It is fake url we set to get their callback result.

When we implement in our program to call that link , we get errors as "The remote name could not be resolved: 'return.mytest.com'". I know that error because return.mytest.com does not exist our side. I just want to get callback url value.How can I implement with c#.

Answer (score 1):

In an OAuth2 setup, the callback URL must exist.

The other party will pass the details of the token to that URL so if your callback URL does not exist then they will get an error and you will not get the token.

So either add an endpoint to an existing app, or create a new one, but the bottom line is clear. The callback URL must be a real thing. Otherwise how is another party supposed to communicate with you?

Comment: but why I get token in address bar as https://return.mytest.com/?code=my1234&scope= when call url on browser although get error message " server IP address could not be found." Is it not possible just read url address , not response?